# MySQL insert data with fixed values and multiple select results

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

Suppose I have a table structure like below:

**notification_table**

```
| id | receiver_id | type | content | time |
```

The receiver id is from a user table:

**user_table**

```
| id | username |
```

And the content and time are from a broadcast table:

**broadcast_table**

```
| id | content | time |
```

So when I need to insert into this notification table, I need to select id from users and select content+time from broadcasts, and the type is fixed to "system_broadcast". Can I do this in one query?

I tried

```
INSERT INTO notification_table (receiver_id, type, content, time) 
VALUES (
       (SELECT id FROM user_table WHERE username='test' LIMIT 1), 
        'system_broadcast', 
       (SELECT content, time FROM broadcast_table)
)
```

But it returns error like "mysql Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using `insert . . . select`.  This seems to match the intention of your original query:

```
INSERT INTO notification_table (receiver_id, type, content, time) 
    SELECT (SELECT id FROM user_table WHERE username = 'test' LIMIT 1), 
           'system_broadcast',
           content, time
    FROM broadcast_table;
```

Note that this will insert one row for every row in `broadcast_table`.  You might want a `where` clause or `limit` to get only particular rows.

Comment: Yes, it works. And I do have the limit condition clause which I can handle myself. Thanks.